# How are hero animations done?

Tags: ux-designer, animation

An example could be seen on [Valueact](http://valueact.com/) website. I need some direction as to how this is implemented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is done using CSS animation. You can set up DOM elements to animate - change size, position, rotate, and so on, using a (relatively) standardised set of CSS properties.

More info here:
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp

They also appear to be using a Javascript library called Tweenmax, which seems to provide more granular control over animations, such as staggering different animations to appear at different times.

https://greensock.com/tweenmax

Comment: Hmm, i see. Gracias!